# Iterate over a model's associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

Is there a way to programmatically iterate over all of the associations of an instance of a model? Something like this:

```
person_to_copy = Person.find params[:id]
new_person = person_to_copy.dup
person.has_one_associations.for_each |association_name| do
  new_sibling = person_to_copy[:association_name].dup
  new_person[:association_name] = new_sibling
end
```

(As suggested by my example, I want to eventually write a function to deep-copy an instance of a model. I think what I'm asking for is an important step along the way.)